CloudWatch Query to give results based on independent but correlated log event
Every request in my application logs two log events. They are in the following format.
Log event 1----> Found Source : A | CorrelationId : GuidA
Log event 2----> Total Processing Time : 15 | CorrelationId : GuidA
Log event 3----> Found Source : B | CorrelationId : GuidB
Log event 4----> Total Processing Time : 35 | CorrelationId : GuidB
Log event 5----> Found Source : B | CorrelationId : GuidC
Log event 6----> Total Processing Time : 45 | CorrelationId : GuidC
I would like a query which provides processing times for a given source from all request. For instance, I would like to know processing time for requests which have source as B. The query should return results as:



Processing Time
CorrelationId




35
GuidB


45
GuidC



I tried the nested query approach.
However, I understand that insights doesn't support subquery?
